# How can I find the WCF error information in Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-service-runtime

We are getting this exception when I have hosted the WCF service in Azure for few operation contract methods. It is returning List of known object from server. If I return the string or bool instead of List then that is working fine.

> {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
>      at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_9(Object sendState)
>      at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(Object sendState)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
>      at ReportServiceClient.ReportServiceClientChannel.EndGetData(IAsyncResult result)
>      at ReportServiceClient.IReportService.EndGetData(IAsyncResult result)
>      at ReportServiceClient.OnEndGetData(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)}

#### Note:

If the same service hosted in Webserver then that is working fine.

How can I find the WCF error information in Azure?

If I hosted the service in Webserver then I will enable the trace for Service and find the exact cause of service failure from svclog file. But I cannot do the same in Azure.  Is it possible to find the error information in Azure?

Comment: How did you enable the WCF service trace?  (via web.config or programatically?)

Comment: By far the simplest way is to enable Remote Desktop for your webrole. Log in to your webrole VM (temporarily deploy just one instance so it's easier to debug) and enable WCF tracing just like you do in your own hosted WebServer. If this is for the purpose of a once-off debugging session, then that's what I'd do. It's also possible to enable WCF logs and configure WA diagnostics to upload the log to storage, but it's more involved.